# How to show the stability of $L^2$ projection?

Tags: finite-element, numerics

If $\mathcal{T}_h$ is a regular and quasi-uniform triangulation of $\Omega$, and $V_h$ is the $H^1$-conforming linear finite element space. Moreover, let $P_h$ be the $L^2$ projection to $V_h\subset H^1(\Omega)$, i.e.,
\begin{equation}
(P_hu,v_h)=(u,v_h),\quad\quad \forall v_h\,\in V_h\quad\quad (1).
\end{equation}
How to show the stability of the following result
\begin{equation}
\|P_hu\|_{H^1(\Omega)}\leq C\|u\|_{H^1(\Omega)}\quad\quad (2).
\end{equation}

By choosing $v_h=P_hu$, we have
\begin{equation}
\|P_hu\|_{L^2(\Omega)}^2=(u,p_hu)\leq \|u\|_{L^2(\Omega)}\|P_hu\|_{L^2(\Omega)},
\end{equation}
which shows that
\begin{equation}
\|P_hu\|_{L^2(\Omega)}\leq \|u\|_{L^2(\Omega)}.
\end{equation}
But, how to show the result $(2)$? Could anyone give some suggestions? Thank you!

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "how to show result (1)?" This is the *definition* of the projection.

Answer (score 2):

I'd assume you want to prove $(2)$, and $u\in V\subset H^1(\Omega)$.

You already proved that $\|P_hu\|_{L^2(\Omega)}\leq \|u\|_{L^2(\Omega)}$, which is just one more step to arrive
$$
\|P_hu\|_{H^1(\Omega)}\leq C_0\left(\|u\|_{H^1(\Omega)}+\|u\|_{L^2(\Omega)}\right).
$$
Then you prove
$$
\|u\|_{L^2(\Omega)} \leq C_1\|u\|_{H^1(\Omega)}.
$$

Combine the above two inequalities, you get
$$
\|P_hu\|_{H^1(\Omega)}\leq C\|u\|_{H^1(\Omega)}.
$$

What listed above is just a process for the proof other than its rigorous detail, which could be found in the literature, such as [Brenner & Scott](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9780387759333).